# How to remove these trim clip retaining fasteners?

Tags: body-work

I’m trying to remove this cowl/scuttle panel in order to get under and clean the area which has leaves and filth inside.

I have managed to to remove the circle clips marked a in the picture.

1. I started taking the rubber line off which I didn’t need to and dislodged it from the clip anchor and am having a hard time putting it back in.  Is leading to tears etc.  How can I put the rubber ack on properly?
2. Clip c seems to be holding the panel in what is the correct way to undo it?  I have added a picture of it based on the part number and it seems very hard to remove.  May I aswell just break and replace?

[image]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have a good look at the rivets - some have pins you push out (which obviously means you need to catch them so you don't loose them :) ), others have internal pins that you pull so the ears then can move in... All about looking to see how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Those are plastic push rivets and they can be difficult to get out and will often break.  There is a special tool for these such as:

[image: Push Rivet Tool]

You should be able to pick one up at any auto parts store.  Also most will have similar rivets, you may need to get a couple of replacements if any break.

Comment: I have added a pic of the clip based on part number.  Are these the clips You had in mind?  Are you saying I just need to put the tool you have linked at the bottom push up and it will come out?it seems very strong will the tool provide presssure enough to make it skinny and push it out?

Comment: You slide the tool between the rivet and the fastened part and pry the rivet out.  As far as those clips, I can't say.  When you get one out take it to the auto parts store and find a similar one.  The diameter of the hole and the length of the rivet are the important factors.  I don't think the clips you are showing are the right kind.